# PHP efficient way to combine two associative arrays into one multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays

**This is the first problem:**

I have two Associative Arrays, one containing sales persons and one containing clients.

```
  $salesPersons = array(
    array(
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "Mr Smith",
      "email" => "mrsmith@email.com",
      "clients" => array()
    ),
    array(
      "id" => "2",
      "name" => "James Bond",
      "email" => "jamesbond@email.com",
      "clients" => array()
    )
  );

  $clients = array(
    array(
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "Lucifer Enterprises",
      "salesPersonId" => "1"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => "2",
      "name" => "Charlies Chocolate Factory",
      "salesPersonId" => "1"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => "3",
      "name" => "Geckos Investments",
      "salesPersonId" => "2"
    ),
  );
```

I want to map $salesPersons['id'] to clients['salesPersonId'] by ID and return a multidimensional associative array like this:

```
  $result_i_want = array(
    array(
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "Mr Smith",
      "email" => "mrsmith@email.com",
      "clients" => array(
        array(
          "id" => "1",
          "name" => "Lucifer Enterprises",
        ),
        array(
          "id" => "2",
          "name" => "Charlies Chocolate Factory",
        ),
      )
    ),
    array(
      "id" => "2",
      "name" => "James Bond",
      "email" => "jamesbond@email.com",
      "clients" => array(
        array(
          "id" => "3",
          "name" => "Geckos Investments",
        ),
      )
    )
  );
```

**My solution to the first problem**

I have solved it using nested foreach-loops and array_push

```
  $result = array();

  foreach ($clients as $c_record) {
    foreach ($salesPersons as $s_record) {
      if ($c_record['salesPersonId'] == $s_record['id']) {
        array_push($s_record['clients'], array(
          "id" => $c_record['id'],
          "name" => $c_record['name']
        ));
        array_push($result, $s_record);
      }
    }
  }
```

**The remaining problem**

This solution doesn't seem to be very efficient.
For each client record I check all sales persons to see if there is a match. I think the number of computations are:

```
no. of clients * no. of sales persons
```

I have a huge database and also need to add even more dimensions by mapping projects to the clients and deliverables to the projects. I think this could pose a problem.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way to get the same result?

Comment: Where are these arrays originating from? Are these two separate query results?

Comment: These are two separate GET requests from an API of a web application. I get JSON data which I decode to an associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an index :
you need to access your `salesPerson` entries by id, you can start by creating an associative array `id => salesPerson`, and then use this associative array in your loop.

```
$salesById = array();

foreach ($salesPersons as $s_record) {
    $salesById[ $s_record['id'] ] = $s_record;
}

$result = array();

foreach ($clients as $c_record) {
    $s_record = $salesById[ $c_record['salesPersonId'] ];

    if ($s_record == null) {
        // you may want to handle invalid ids in the client array
        // one way is to simply ignore this client record :
        continue;
    }

    array_push($s_record['clients'], array(
      "id" => $c_record['id'],
      "name" => $c_record['name']
    ));
    array_push($result, $s_record);
}
```

---

*Notes*

There may be a problem in the way you create your `$result` array :
if a sales person has `n` clients, the `$result` array will reference that sales person `n` times.

Look closer into what result you actually want, you may simply want to return `$salesPersons`, or `$salesById`.

Comment: As you point out the solution above results in duplicate salesPersons in the result array with one client each. I'm looking for the same result as in the question where one salesPerson can have multiple clients. I'll try to tweak your code but if you have a solution for this please share so that question can be answered

Comment: last sentence : "you may simply want to return $salesPersons, or $salesById."

Answer (score 0):

As LeGEC said:

> you need to access your salesPerson entries by id, you can start by creating an associative array id => salesPerson, and then use this associative array in your loop.

You need to set the index of your arrays with the id:

```
<?php
$salesPersons = array(
    1 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "Mr Smith",
        "email" => "mrsmith@email.com",
        "clients" => array()
    ),
    2 => array(
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "James Bond",
        "email" => "jamesbond@email.com",
        "clients" => array()
    )
);

$clients = array(
    1 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "Lucifer Enterprises",
        "salesPersonId" => "1"
    ),
    2 => array(
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "Charlies Chocolate Factory",
        "salesPersonId" => "1"
    ),
    3 => array(
        "id" => "3",
        "name" => "Geckos Investments",
        "salesPersonId" => "2"
    ),
);
```

Then:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($clients as $id => $c_record) {
    if (isset($salesPersons[$id])) {
        $result[] = array_merge($clients[$id], $salesPersons[$id]);
    } else {
        $result[] = $clients[$id];
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Result here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e590bdb5aaea2794fc5a04ee60f61db766129664

#### PS:

My code works with your use case, but it will not work if the size of the `$salesPersons` array is bigger than the `$clients` array